# htaccess - Multiple variables for rewrite url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make:

```
domain.com/watch.php?user=xyz&vid=465ddd55
```

to

```
domain.com/xyz/video-title_465ddd55
```

This is what i have but it is not working...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})$ watch.php?user=$1&vid=$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this rule in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder).
Also, make sure **mod_rewrite** is enabled

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/[^_]+_([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /watch.php?user=$1&vid=$2 [L]
```